# react-native-router-flux: How to prevent Tab Scene history stack from being reset when changing between tabs?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have a `Router` setup with 2 tab scenes:

- **Tab 1:** have 2 navigable scenes (static screens);

  - **Screen A:** have a button to navigate to **Screen B**;
  - **Screen B:** just have a text;
- **Tab 2:** just have 1 static screen.

  - **Screen C:** just have a text;

The code is as follows.

**app.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Tab from '../tab';
import ScreenA from './a';
import ScreenB from './b';
import ScreenC from './c';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
        <Scene key="root">
          <Scene key="tabbar" tabs={true}>

            <Scene key="tab1" title="Tab 1" icon={Tab}>
              <Scene key="a" title="Screen A" component={ScreenA} />
              <Scene key="b" title="Screen B" component={ScreenB} />
            </Scene>

            <Scene key="tab2" title="Tab 2" icon={Tab}>
              <Scene key="c" title="Screen C" component={ScreenC} />
            </Scene>

          </Scene>
        </Scene>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

The screens are pretty simple too.

**a.js:**

```
export default class ScreenA extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>This is Screen A</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => Actions.b()}>
          <Text>Go to Screen B</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**b.js:**

```
export default class ScreenB extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>This is Screen B</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**c.js:**

```
export default class ScreenC extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>This is Screen C</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

## Use case:

- The app renders Screen A (in Tab 1);
- Click on button in Screen A: the app navigates to **Screen B** (still in Tab 1);
- Click on Tab 2: the app navigates to **Screen C** (in Tab 2).
- Click on Tab 1: the app navigates to **Screen A** (in Tab 1) and **NOT** to Screen B, as expected.

`react-native-router-flux` is not retaining the Tabs' history stack when we get back to them. Or am I doing something wrong here?

**Packages versions:**

- react v15.3.2
- react-native v0.34.1
- react-native-router-flux v3.36.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in **react-native-router-flux** package, and it was fixed in this [pull request](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/pull/1312).

Comment: How do I make app navigate to screen A instead of screen B when clicking link to tab 1 from inside of tab 2?