# Reseting Tab scene history stack when changing tabs

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

My question is actually about desiring the exact behavior of a bug illustrated in [react-native-router-flux: How to prevent Tab Scene history stack from being reseted when changing between tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275587/react-native-router-flux-how-to-prevent-tab-scene-history-stack-from-being-rese)

I am copying the exact scenario description and code snippets from the linked question as it is exactly what I need

> I have a `Router` setup with 2 tab scenes:
>
> - **Tab 1:** have 2 navigable scenes (static screens);
>
>   - **Screen A:** have a button to navigate to **Screen B**;
>   - **Screen B:** just have a text;
> - **Tab 2:** just have 1 static screen.
>
>   - **Screen C:** just have a text;
>
> The code is as follows.
>
> **app.js:**
>
> ```
> import React from 'react';
> import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';
> import Tab from '../tab';
> import ScreenA from './a';
> import ScreenB from './b';
> import ScreenC from './c';
>
>
> export default class App extends React.Component {
>   render(){
>     return (
>       <Router>
>         <Scene key="root">
>           <Scene key="tabbar" tabs={true}>
>
>             <Scene key="tab1" title="Tab 1" icon={Tab}>
>               <Scene key="a" title="Screen A" component={ScreenA} />
>               <Scene key="b" title="Screen B" component={ScreenB} />
>             </Scene>
>
>             <Scene key="tab2" title="Tab 2" icon={Tab}>
>               <Scene key="c" title="Screen C" component={ScreenC} />
>             </Scene>
>
>           </Scene>
>         </Scene>
>       </Router>
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> The screens are pretty simple too.
>
> **a.js:**
>
> ```
> export default class ScreenA extends React.Component {
>   render(){
>     return (
>       <View>
>         <Text>This is Screen A</Text>
>         <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => Actions.b()}>
>           <Text>Go to Screen B</Text>
>         </TouchableHighlight>
>       </View>
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **b.js:**
>
> ```
> export default class ScreenB extends React.Component {
>   render(){
>     return (
>       <View>
>         <Text>This is Screen B</Text>
>       </View>
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **c.js:**
>
> ```
> export default class ScreenC extends React.Component {
>   render(){
>     return (
>       <View>
>         <Text>This is Screen C</Text>
>       </View>
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

The desired use case:

- The app renders Screen A (in Tab 1);
- Click on button in Screen A: the app navigates to **Screen B** (still in Tab 1);
- Click on Tab 2: the app navigates to **Screen C** (in Tab 2).
- Click on Tab 1: the app navigates to **Screen A** (in Tab 1) and **NOT** to Screen B, as it is by design.

I know I can implement a custom reducer to solve this issue but I believe there must be a more straightforward solution I am probably overlooking.